# Smallest Ellipsoid circumscribing a rectangular prism

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Given a rectangular prism with the dimensions $57$ by $23$ by $46$ (centred at the origin) what are the cross terms for the Ellipsoid that circumscribes it?

Comment: What have you tried? People on the site generally want to see where you're at before possibly doing your homework for you.

Comment: I have tried using the ratio of one side of the prism against another to solve for the cross terms. I’ve tried the same using the volume of the prism knowing that it’s volume should be equal to 8abc where abc are the cross terms. I’ve only taken one calculus class and two linear algebra and this problem is for a personal project not school related and clearly beyond my abilities and education

Answer (score 1):

Scale your prism in the axial directions and think what the "smallest" ellipsoid would be for the resulting cube.

Comment: Would it not be a sphere with a diameter equal to $\sqrt{2x^2+x^2}$ where $x$ is the length of an edge cube? I don’t see how this helps with the specific rectangular prism I’m using.

Comment: Once you have a bounding sphere, mathematically stretch both the cube (and the sphere) so that the cube now matches your rectangular prism.  Of course the property of smallest bounding sphere (ellipsoid) remains...

Answer (score 0):

Does this figure help you understand the concept?

[image]

Comment: Are you suggesting that I can start with a unit cube and circle and simply stretch each axis like this $\frac 1 {57}^2 x^2+\frac 1 {23}^2 y^2+\frac 1 {46}^2 z^2=1$

Comment: Yep...  simply replace $x \to 57 x$, etc.

Comment: So the simplified ellipse equation would be $\frac {x^2}{57}+\frac {y^2}{23}+\frac {z^2}{46}=1$? I feel like I'm missing something again because I know that isn't correct given the 3d graph I'm looking at doesn't match yours.

Answer (score 0):

So, the actual answer I was looking for is that the cross term's ratio with its respective section of the rectangular prism is $\sqrt{3}$. Given the size of the ellipse, half one axis of the rectangular prism is the cross term divided by $\sqrt{3}$, and given the size of the prism, one axis divided by two multiplied by $\sqrt{3}$ is the cross term for that axis.

Thank you all ever so much for overcomplicating something that should've been a one-sentence answer with your attempts to teach problem-solving.